# OpenXML reference document parts multiple time

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

With OpenXML, is there a way to add a document part like word paragraph then reference it multiple times in different pages of same document?

My application reads a .docx file that includes 50 paragraphs, and generats multiple copies of same paragraphs but in random order, some times paragraphs include images, formulas ... etc, the size of generated file are becoming high because those objets are repeated multiple time. I'm looking for a way to insert the object once and reference it multiple times.

Comment: Here's Greg Maxey's page with 9 ways to do this in Word: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/repeating_data.html

Comment: All 9 ways are dealing with text only, and some of them just create copies. I want repeat a complete paragraph the might include images and other objects. The article gave me some ideas that might lead to a solution.